# Merging two query result based on condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have two query results.I need to merge the query result based on a condition.

```
$portfolio = DB::table('architects_portfolio')->get();

 $img=DB::table('architects_portfolio_images')
          ->distinct()->get(['architects_images_id']);
```

and my condition to merge is

```
architects_portfolio.id = architects_portfolio_images.architects_images_id
```

I have my first table 'architects_portfolio' which contain portfolio and second table 'architects_portfolio_images' which contain images of portfolio.I need to get only one image for now.But I get all images of portfolio now by using below code.But I need only one

```
 $architect = User::find($user_id)->architect;               
 $portfolio = ArchitectsPortfolio::join('architects_portfolio_images as images', 'architects_portfolio.id', '=', 'images.architects_images_id')
            ->where('architects_portfolio.architects_id', $architect->id)
            ->select('architects_portfolio.id', 'architects_portfolio.architects_id', 'architects_portfolio.name', 'architects_portfolio.description', 'images.filename','images.architects_images_id')
            ->distinct()->get(['images.architects_images_id']);
```

My tables
[architects_potfolio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E380l.png)

[architects_portfolio_images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkKOp.png)

Comment: use join method in your query

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? Merge could be of rows (i.e. a union) or columns (i.e. a join)

Comment: join will bring all images.I need only one image for particular portfolio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of merging we can make use of following code

```
$data = Architect::where("user_id", $user_id)->first();
$architect = User::find($user_id)->architect;
        $portfolio = ArchitectsPortfolio::where('architects_portfolio.architects_id', $architect->id)->paginate(6);
        foreach ($portfolio as $r) {
            $image = ArchitectsPortfolioImages::where('architects_images_id', $r->id)->first();
            if ($image) {
                $r->filename = $image->filename;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $querys = DB::table('architects_portfolio');    
 $querys->select('architects_portfolio_images.architects_images_id');
 $querys->join('architects_portfolio','architects_portfolio.id','=','architects_portfolio_images.architects_images_id')->distinct()->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
$rsltArchitectDetails = DB::table('architects_portfolio')
                    ->select('architects_portfolio_images.architects_images_id')
                    ->join('architects_portfolio_images', 'architects_portfolio.id' , '=', 'architects_portfolio_images.architects_images_id')
                    ->distinct()
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships), then you could just load portfolios with related images:

```
$portfolios = ArhitectPortfolio::with('images')->get();
```

To make it work, you just need to define the `images` relationship in the `ArhitectPortfolio` model:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ArchitectPortfolioImage::class, 'architects_images_id');
}
```